# Is there a "curl -L" equivalent in java to handle url redirection?

Tags: java, curl, redirect

curl -L does a nice job of getting the contents of the URL when there is a 301/302 redirection.
I did some research and couldn't find a proper/good solution for this issue in java. There are some solutions to check the Location header and iterate. 
Is there a better solution in Java yet?

Comment: Are you using a specific library ? Okhttp for example has client.setFollowRedirects(true)

Comment: This depends on what you use in Java. There are so many ways to get contents of the URL. Normally you'll use one of the HTTP client libraries, most of them have "follow redirects" functionality.

Comment: java.net.HttpURLConnection follows redirects default - as does most other HTTP client libraries for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses all!

Totally my bad. I was trying redirection from http URL and the redirect was going to an https which is not possible per specs.

Managed to get the equivalent https url and it worked like a charm for HttpURLConnection.